# How do I fix this recurring 0 problem in the celsius-fahrenheit conversion?

Tags: python, python-3.x

was creating a celsius to Fahrenheit calculator and my code is simply:

```
c = float(input())
f = (c*(9/5))+32
print(f)
```

However, when I test this code with 52.0 as an input, the output is 126.000000001 instead of just 126.0. Why is this so and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken you could just print: `print(f"{f:.2f}")` (see [python string formatting](http://zetcode.com/python/fstring/)).

Comment: Or you could use the ```round()``` function, per my answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `round()` function

```
c = float(input())
f = (c*(9/5))+32
f = round(f, 2)
print(f)
```